# Android - spinner selected item doesn't detect by the listener

Tags: android

Can anyone help me?

The spinner2 doesn't show the selected position wherein it must be showed using Toast(below the code).

I cannot find what's wrong with my code. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5.67"
    android:entries="@array/groupLamp />
```

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*parameters*/
        final Integer incandescant[]={5,15,25,35,40,60,75,100,125,150};
        final Integer led[] = {0,2,3,5,8,13,15,20,23,28};
        final Integer cfl[] = {0,0,0,0,13,15,25,30,40,45};
        final Integer fluorescent[] = {40,40,20,55};

        Button btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Incandescant");
        list.add("CFL");
        list.add("Flourescent");
        list.add("Others");

        final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                list2.clear();

                if(pos==0){
                    for(Integer ctr: incandescant){
                        list2.add(ctr+ " watts");
                    }

                }else if(pos==1){
                    for(Integer ctr: led){
                        list2.add(ctr +" watts");
                    }
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list2);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: just make sure your list2 is populated as it depends on spinner1 item selection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange - your spinner's1 ID in the XML is `spinner2`, but in the code you refer to `spnExistLamp` and `spnElampWat`. So, there is no connection between the XML and the code.

Comment: I edited my code above. I apologize because I tried to change spinner Id's to become more friendly.

Comment: do you see a list on clicking spinner2 in order to select one choice?

Comment: @michelleAsitura `list2` is empty, use `list2.addAll(list)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly linking the views in xml.

`android:id="@+id/spinner2"` in xml

But in your code you are using

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnExistLamp);
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnElampWat);
```

**Plz make following changes in your code**

```
final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list2);  //------ line location changed.

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                list2.clear();

                if(pos==0){
                    for(Integer ctr: incandescant){
                        list2.add(ctr+ " watts");
                    }

                }else if(pos==1){
                    for(Integer ctr: led){
                        list2.add(ctr +" watts");
                    }
                }

                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();    //------- line added
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: hi, thank you. I changed the values..   Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2); .. But still Toast doesn't show.

Comment: you were not calling  dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); in your code. As you change the content of list you need to notify it. I have pasted the changes. Its working now.